# Connection timeout for accessing S3 bucket from lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have some static files in S3 bucket and I ONLY want my lambda function to read it, all other paths should be blocked. How should I configure it? Is it on S3 side, or VPC/Lambda side or both? I have created endpoints for my VPC and even make the two files public. But when I access from my lambda function, I still get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 

<bucket-name>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443


[<bucket-name>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/52.219.88.152] failed: connect timed 
   out
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that the network connected to S3 was blocked ,you need to modify S3 bucket policy and give lambda read permission.

Following AWS doc will help you to understand and define rule and policy for S3

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html

Also check your CORS setting

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html